# Scala Override Generic Method from a Trait

Tags: scala

I have a trait definition like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def dbService[M[_]]: DBService[M[_]]
  def appConfig: AppConfig
  def supervisorActor: ActorRef
}
```

I have an implementation of this trait that looks like this:

```
    object MyTrait {

      def apply(system: ActorSystem, actorMaterializer: Materializer): MyTrait = new MyTrait {

        override val appConfig: AppConfig = AppConfig.load()
// Get the ERROR here saying Value dbService overrides nothing        
override val dbService: DBService[Task] = DBServiceT.asTask(appConfig.dbConfig)(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)

        override val supervisorActor: ActorRef =
          system.actorOf(
            SupervisorActor.props(appConfig)(monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global),
            s"${appConfig.appName}-supervisor"
          )
      }
    }
```

My DBService trait looks like this:

```
trait DBService[M[_]] {
  def allPowerPlants(fetchOnlyActive: Boolean): M[Seq[PowerPlantRow]]
  def powerPlantsPaginated(filter: PowerPlantFilter): M[Seq[PowerPlantRow]]
  def allPowerPlantsPaginated(fetchOnlyActive: Boolean, pageNumber: Int): M[Seq[PowerPlantRow]]
  def powerPlantById(id: Int): M[Option[PowerPlantRow]]
  def newPowerPlant(powerPlantRow: PowerPlantRow): M[Int]
}
```

I then have an implementation that looks like this:

```
class DBServiceTask private (dbConfig: DBConfig)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends DBService[Task] { self =>

....
....

}
```

When I tried this, I get an error in my MyTrait object that says:

```
Value dbService overrides nothing
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot `object MyTrait extends MyTrait` maybe?

Comment: Nope! That is not the problem! I have edited my post! Take a look now!

Comment: Try with `type M[_]` in the `trait` then fix that to `Task` in your implementation.

Comment: I don't want to pollute the trait with a Type definition! Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This signature:

`def dbService[M[_]]: DBService[M[_]]`

describes something that can create a DBService for ANY type constructor `M[_]`. For it to typecheck it must be able to create **all** of:

- `DBService[Task]`
- `DBService[Future]`
- `DBService[Array]`
- `DBService[Option]`
- `DBService[Ordering]`
- ...and so on

Since your implementation can only produce a value for *a single* `M[_]` (`Task` in your case), you cannot have that signature.

Your options include moving a type parameter to a trait definition, either as a type parameter:

```
trait MyTrait[M[_]] {
  def dbService: DBService[M] // also note that [_] part should not be here
}
```

or a type member:

```
trait MyTrait {
  type M[_]
  def dbService: DBService[M]
}
```

The latter, however, might be a nuisance to use

**EDIT**: You also have the option of specifying `Task` directly, of course:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def dbService: DBService[Task]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`val dbService: DBService[Task]` is a value of type `DBService[Task]`, whereas you need to define a function that takes a type as "parameter": `def dbService[M[_]]: DBService[M[_]]`

I think you want your trait to look like this:

```
trait MyTrait[M[_]] {
  def dbService: DBService[M[_]]
  def appConfig: AppConfig
  def supervisorActor: ActorRef
}
```